# OSX Terminal $PATH strange characters

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I have encountered some strange characters in Terminal's `$PATH` variable.

```
$ echo $PATH

/opt/local/bin:...(many similar entries)...:/usr/local/git/bin??n’export
```

**`??n’export`** is what I'm talking about. How do I remove it? I looked in `.bacshrc`, `.bash_profile` and similar files, but everything seemed normal there. Problem is that I can't install some new programs with "broken" `$PATH`.

I'm using bash in Terminal version 2.7.1 and macOS Sierra — Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you get when you run `$ bash -l 'echo $PATH'`?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet He will probably get `bash: echo $PATH: No such file or directory`. didin't missed the `-c`? :)

Comment: @jm666 right. It's too late to edit it. Please run: `bash -l -c 'echo $PATH'`

Comment: @GregoryNisbet `/opt/local/bin:...(many similar entries)...:/usr/local/git/bin??n’export?n’export`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Strange entries came from /etc/profile file.

Comment: Please expand this answer. What was in `/etc/profile` that caused the problem, and why was it there? Did you modify `/etc/profile` yourself?
 Without this information, though your problem may be solved, it doesn't particularly help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

The following

```
perl -e 'printf q{export %s="%s";},$_,join(":",grep{-d $_&&!$seen{$_}++}split/:/,$ENV{$_}), $_ for(qw(PATH))'
```

will generate for you an new `export PATH=.....` line, but with cleaned elements. (e.g. no duplicate entries, and removed all nonexiststent directories).

you should copy and paste the result into your `$HOME/.profile` instead of the existing `PATH` line.

Comment: do we know for sure that the strange garbage in the `PATH` got added by the `.profile` or `.bashrc` files?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet in OSX bash uses (by vendor) the `.profile` file. Also the OP said, that the checked the `.bash_profile`. **But, yes**, it could be in more places. The main point is, the script should generate an *cleaned* `PATH`, probably the directories with "strange characters" doesn't exists in the filesystem.

Comment: Yes, I checked all files that you mentioned, but I couldn't find any suspicious entries.

Comment: @jm666 This is what file looks like now:                                                                                                                                                                      `export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*` Which `PATH` line do I have to replace? Only first?

Comment: @omas13 the outout from the script should be the **lastest**. Even could be the very lastest line in the `.profile`. **but** youre right, here isn't anything wrong - so, looks like the problem starts somewhere elsewhere ...

Comment: @jm666 Is it possible to somehow reset/delete `PATH` variable and than add all current `PATH` entries back manually?

Comment: exactly for that is the above script. helps you create an clean `export PATH...` line. Of course, you can edit it manually anytime... But need be careful, and do not enter some special characters when editing...